# Remove � from string

Tags: java, string

I have a custom class that I use to create a "unit". After the unit is created i store them in a ArrayList. But when I try to get the values back, I get some weird �� before the string.

```
if (data.isSelected()) {
  response.add(data.getName() + "," + data.getSerialNumber());
}
```

Returns:

```
[��BMW 320d Xdrive, 222201176��]
```

Does anyone have an idea where these come from, and how can I remvove them?
Please tell me if I need to provide more code.

EDIT:

```
public ArrayList<SampleData> dataList;
System.out.println("Confirming data: " + valArr[i]); // here the chracters are normal
dataList.add(new SampleData(valArr[0].replace("[", "\0"), valArr[1].replace("]", "\0"), false));
System.out.println("Trying: " + dataList.get(i).toStrings()); // here i get the wierd "?" signs.
```

Comment: That looks like an encoding problem. How is the data encoded? What encoding do you use for output? "U+FFFD � replacement character used to replace an unknown or unrepresentable character" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: yes, add more code - how do you print it?

Comment: Check the encoding, when you save your data or when you read it.

Comment: If you _really_ don't care about non-ascii chars simply remove them: `str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");`

Comment: provide the code you used to input data.

Comment: I added the code where I store the data to the list. Should I just use `string.replace();`?
Edit: I remebered now that I have characters like "ÅÄÖ" in the data, maybe this could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\0` is not a printable character. Don't replace `[]` with `\0` and the � won't appear.

**Edit:**

If you want to remove the brackets `[]`, use

```
valArr[0].replace("[", "")
```

Comment: +1: the correct way to do it -- don't add it to the string in the first place

Comment: Thanks, this removed the "�". Is there another correct way to remove the brackets?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the brackets? We don't know enough about what you are trying to do to give you better advise.

Comment: I want to remove the brackets for displaying in a ListView in a android application.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove � as follows. may be issue with character encoding. It has Unicode value 0xFFFD

```
    String returnStr="[��BMW 320d Xdrive, 222201176��]";
    System.out.println(returnStr.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\�",""));
```